# How to completely eliminate blank whitescreen in ionic 2 project

Tags: android, ionic2, splash-screen

When the splashscreen finishes loading, the app sometimes go blank and I have to press the home key and open the app again before it works. This happens frequently enough to make it very annoying. Please how can I get rid of it completely. Have seen other solutions but they didn't work for me. Am building for Android.

Comment: I wish it was as easy as setting `.white-screen { display: none; }` You're experiencing the 'White Screen of Death' *insert scary sound*. Check out this guide on how to debug it (ionic 1 guide but google dev tools should still work) http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-debug-the-white-screen-of-death-in-your-ionic-app/

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the blank screen you can use a theme related to your Activity, for example :

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/fondo_splash</item>
   </style>
```

into the `android:windowBackground` property you must define a backgroud that will be present all the time, for example an image (stored into `@drawable/` )

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bakg_image_splash</item>
```

or a color (`@color/`):

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_splash</item>
```

Inside our `AndroidManifest.xml` we can define the theme for our application :

```
  <application
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

o an specific Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
   android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
```

With this we can assure to have a background (drawable or color), and avoid the blank screen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: But this just changes the color of the blank screen. He wants it gone (i believe) since it forces him to restart his application

Comment: This keep all the time a background to avoid the blank screen between transitions.

Comment: But this issue *'and I have to press the home key and open the app again before it works'* will still remain

Comment: @Ivaro18 did you found any solution

Comment: @MohanGopi nope, never had this issue so don't know what's causing it